# Processing 3.0.1: Best way to scroll RSS feed

Tags: rss, processing

I am new to Processing and I am trying to start small by combining some of the built-in examples.  I am scrolling an RSS feed from Google News over an image.  It seems to work just fine but the code is limited to scrolling one headline at a time.  What if I want to limit the space between each headline?  I thought of two ways to do this:  the first is to `headlines` into a really long string.  The second is to make two `headlines` scroll at once.  The problem with the second method is that, if I move on to bigger images or start scrolling smaller strings (like stock quotes), I will need to have many statements for scrolling many `headlines`.  Is there a better way that I am not thinking of?

```
/**
 * Scrolling Rss Feeds
 * 
 * Scroll headlines from Google News on top of an image
 */

PImage img;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage
float x;  // horizontal location of headline
XML xml;
String[] headlines;
int index = 0;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  x = width;
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  img = loadImage("moonwalk.jpg");  // Load the image into the program 

  // The URL for the XML document
  String url = "http://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss";
  // Load the XML document
  xml = loadXML(url);
  // Grab the element we want
  XML[] headers = xml.getChildren("channel/item/title");
  headlines = new String[headers.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
     headlines[i] = headers[i].getContent();
  }
}

void draw() {
  // Displays the image at its actual size at point (0,0)
  image(img, 0, 0);
  textSize(32);
  text(headlines[index], x, 90);
  x = x - 3;
  float w = textWidth(headlines[index]);
  if (x < -w) {
    x = width; 
    index = (index + 1) % headlines.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is.What exactly do you mean by `I will need to have many statements for scrolling many headlines`? You're already using an array to scroll multiple headlines, aren't you?

Comment: I am already scrolling many headlines but only one at a time.  What is the best way to have multiple headlines on the screen at a time?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you want to do. There is no "best", it's completely up to you. If you tell us exactly what you want to do (maybe with mockup images), we can help you work through it. But we can't tell you what the best way to proceed is.

Comment: I want to have multiple headlines on the screen at the same time.  Right now, you have to wait for one headline to roll off before you see the next:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0F1yWDNKi2vVjE4RVJaUTRuN0k/view?usp=sharing

I want it to look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0F1yWDNKi2vX1c0TklPY28zSEk/view?usp=sharing